# An unknown tag shows when adding Ignored Tag

Tags: bug, ignored-tags

An `[...]` tag shows every time I add a new **Ignored Tag**.

[image: ghost_tag]

But when I checked my **Tag Preferences**, there is no `[...]` showing

[image: ignored_tags]

Is this a bug of some sort? Or my karma for ignoring tags?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Thanks for that life-saver tip

Comment: What happens when you click the `[...]` tag? I would have expected it to be a fill-in for elided tags, but I don't see any elided tags in your full list...

Comment: I'm [able to reproduce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGDcj.png) with only the tags Laravel, yii, regex and git in my list. It doesn't happen every time though. This cannot be a relic of a deleted tag because I've never used the 'Ignored Tags' feature. The tag links to `/questions/tagged/%e2%80%a6`.

Comment: The sidebar of the homepage inserts an ellipsis after your 4th ignored tag if you have ignored >= 5 tags. The `...` tag on the preferences page always seems to appear in the 5th position. This can't be a coincidence, right?

Comment: The tag links to the question page of SO

Comment: @Tesseract Hover over the button and read what the actual link is -- it's possible it's linking somewhere else that's redirected.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes It links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: @Tesseract No it doesn't. As I mentioned above, it links to `/questions/tagged/%e2%80%a6` which then redirects to there. [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22zj5.png).

Comment: Note: %e2%80%a6 is the ellipsis character in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: FWIW [the tag doesn't seem to actually exist](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/653408/unicode-tags).

Comment: @Michael I didn't check there, I checked the link in the lower left part. And when I clicked it, it just redirected me to the questions