# Ignored tags lose their remove button when adding new tags

Tags: bug, ignored-tags

While playing around with [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346382/an-unknown-tag-shows-when-adding-ignored-tag?cb=1) I observed that when adding an ignored tag, all other ignored tags lose their remove 'X' buttons.

Before:

[image: Before adding]

After:

[image: After adding]

The buttons will only return if you refresh the page. This is true on both the preferences page and on the sidebar. Interestingly, the same problem does not affect the favourite tags.

---

Similarly, duplicate tags can be added to the ignored list but not the favourite list.